# How to load environment variable in tests with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I'm trying to run a simple test with JavaScript as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import Customization from 'components/onboarding/customization';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('customization render', () => {
  it('should render the Hero page with no issue', () => {
    render(<Customization />);

    const heading = screen.getByText(
      /All the Moodmap at one place!/i
    );

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should call onCLick method on click", () => {
    const mockOnClick = jest.fn()

    const {container} = render(<Customization />);

    const button = getByTestId(container, 'alreadyDownloaded');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)


    // const mockOnClick = jest.fn()
    // const utils = render(<Customization onClick={mockOnClick} />)
    // fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/already downloaded ⟶/i))
    // expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
});
```

When running the tests I'm getting this error

```
No google analytics trackingId defined

   8 |   debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
   9 |   plugins: [
> 10 |     googleAnalyticsPlugin({
     |     ^
  11 |       trackingId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID,
  12 |     }),
```

How do I make this error go away - surely it shouldn't require Google Analytics code given the above, it's not in production when running the test?

#### Update

So I need to make sure the `.env` file is being loaded!

In my `package.json` I've got this Jest setup:

```
"jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)(spec|test).?(m)js?(x)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "mjs"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.m?jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": -10
      }
    }
  },
```

#### updated code to use jest.setup - can't get env to load

So

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});

module.exports = {
  testMatch: [
    "**/?(*.)(spec|test).?(m)js?(x)"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
    ],
    rootDir: "src",
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "mjs"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.m?jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
coverageThreshold: {
    "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": -10
    }
    },
    setupFiles: ["../<rootDir>/.config.env.test"]

};
```

The environment variable files is here:

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID=xxx
```

And this is the code that is not loading the environment variables properly.

```
import Analytics from 'analytics';
import googleAnalyticsPlugin from '@analytics/google-analytics';
import Router from 'next/router';

    // Initialize analytics and plugins
    // Documentation: https://getanalytics.io
    const analytics = Analytics({
      debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      plugins: [
        googleAnalyticsPlugin({
          trackingId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID,
        }),
      ],
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the environment has the `NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID` defined?

Comment: OH man, thanks. How do i add my .env file to jest to be used for testing?

Comment: Check the answer i added

Comment: Does this help https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables?

Answer (score 14):

You can [leverage `loadEnvConfig` from `@next/env`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables) in your tests to make sure environment variables are loaded the same way Next.js does.

---

First setup a `.env.test` to be used in the tests.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID=ga-test-id
```

Next, create a Jest global setup file if you don't have one yet, and reference it in your `jest.config.js`.

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    //...
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

Then add the following code into your Jest global setup file.

```js
// jest.setup.js
import { loadEnvConfig } from '@next/env'

loadEnvConfig(process.cwd())
```

Comment: Great answer, was able to apply it immediately and fixed the issue! Nice approach too using `loadEnvConfig` to mirror how Next.js does it normally.

Answer (score 2):

This message means that the `trackingId` is not defined. As you can see it read from the `process.env`. You need to create this file in the root of your project and call it `.env`. Note that the dot is at the beginning of the filename. The content of the file should be as follow:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID=insert-key-here
```

If your env file is not being read by jest you can do the following:

```js
// In jest.config.js : 

module.exports = {
 ....
    setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/test/setup-tests.ts"]
}


// The file test/test-setup.ts:

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({path: './config.env.test'});
```

You can also check [this article](https://medium.com/better-things-digital/using-dotenv-with-jest-7e735b34e55f) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - I have this env file, I'm more wondering how to load that env file into jest?